# Tunneling through a bastion host on mac for python

Tags: python, ssh, ssh-tunnel

I have to run a python script on some production level data and in order to do that I have to hop through a bastion host. I know on PC you would typically use putty to set up your `ssh tunnels` as you hop to your host and then call localhost.

However how does that work on a Mac? I have my host `xum345434@bastion_host.com` that I hop to. From there how do I setup my aws db connections so that I can simply call one of those connections?

```
mssql-prod.aws.endpoint.com
```

My python script is updating a sql tables at the end of everyday, but I don't know how to setup those connections on a mac.

```
import os
import io
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd
import sys
conn = pyodbc.connect(server = 'localhost,14330', user='usernamae',
                                            password = 'my_password', database = 'Xacation')

cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('''with updated_transations as(select * from my table ''')
```

Comment: `putty` is just an implementation of the Unix `ssh` tool.  Literally anything you can do with `putty` can be done with `ssh`, and usually with the same parameters.

Comment: does that setup go in the bastion host after you login into it?

Comment: What were you doing on Windows?  Did you have something that worked?  The process on the host should not change.

Comment: In putty there's a drop down. Mac is just ssh. I've been trying and failing on hopping through that.

Comment: You presumably need something like `ssh -L 14330:mssql-prod.aws.endpoint.com:1433 sum345434@bastion_host.com` to forward your port 14330 to port 1433 on the AWS endpoint.